# Why does this formula not exclude blank cells despite "IsEmpty" object?

Tags: excel, vba

The below listed formula does not give me the desired result, as it also adds up cells that have no value in them. 'IsEmpty' should however exclude those cells?!

This is my code:

```
`Function ScopeSum() As Long

Dim scopeSumResult As Long
Dim xrow As Long, xcol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim isEmptyVar As Range

With Sheets("Database_UA")

    i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - _
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    xrow = xRowPrint
    xcol = 3

    For j = 1 To i

        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(xrow, xcol).Value) Then
            scopeSumResult = scopeSumResult + .Cells(xrow, xcol).Value - 1
        End If

        xcol = xcol + 1

    Next

End With

ScopeSum = scopeSumResult

End Function`
```

Also find a screenshot of the worksheet here: 
[image]

Range G6:G9 are the cells where the formula is pasted into. E.g.: cell G6 should say 2, not 1.

Thanks for the help, I've tried everything and am really lost!

Comment: There is a built in function for this. What is the value of `i`? I don't think that bit is right.

Comment: "i" just defines how many times the loop within the formula is carried out, as the code applies the formula for various matrices with different sizes. That works fine actually, the problem is that the formula is also calculating wth cell C6 even though that cell is blank. The result is hence not correct, as it always deducts 1 from each cell that is taken into account for the sum. Hope that helps?

Comment: (1) Why are you creating a UDF for something which Excel already has? (2) `xRowPrint` is not defined (3) Why does your formula result vary when it has no arguments? (4) I hadn't noticed your interesting use of `End(xlUp).End(xlUp)`!

Comment: (1) I am not aware of a formula that executes this exact task (finding range of cells with content, adding those contents up and deducting 1 from each of these contents). (2) xRowPrint is defined when the whole code is executed, as xRowPrint is a public variable that is defined in another sub. Please note that the code shown here is just an extract of the whole code as this would become to long.. (4) That works fine actually (same as SHIFT+ARROW UP two times).

Comment: COUNTA? Don't think we can help if relevant code is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the issue with `IsEmpty`, everything works as expected as you can see in  a minimalistic code I tried. So I guess the problem is in some code that you execute outside of the function scope.

```
Function ScopeSum(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cumulative As Double

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            cumulative = cumulative + cell.Value - 1
        End If
    Next cell

    ScopeSum = cumulative
End Function
```

[image]

Also, wouldn't simple

```
=SUM(C3:F3)-COUNTA(C3:F3)
```

just do the same for each row?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to resolve the issue. As you and @SJR already said, the problem actually was a bad declaration of "i" within the function.

Your solution for the formula would work as well. Guess I was thinking in a too complicated way.. Sorry guys, just starting out and sometimes do not see the wood because of all the trees (as we say in Germany;)).
Thanks again!